# Elasticsearch updateByQuery with wait_for_completion

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using updateByQuery to update documents but I am getting **version conflicts error**. How I can handle this error.Can I use wait_for_completion option in elastic search to avoid version conflicts error? is any other solution to handle version conflicts error in updateByQyery?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to specify `conflicts=proceed` in the URL, like this

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
```

Comment: conflicts=proceed will ignore conflicts but still conflicts present. So We handle it? Can I use wait_for_completion option in elastic search to avoid version conflicts error?

Comment: No `wait_for_completion` is not related to conflicts at all. A conflict means that something else modified your document in the meantime. So running update by query a second time usually takes care of the problem